# How to manipulate reduce() output and store it in another file?

Tags: hadoop

I have just started learning Hadoop. I would like to use the output of my `reduce()` and do some manipulations on it. I am working on the new API and have tried using `JobControl`, but  it doesn't seem to work with the new API.

Any way out?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are trying to do. Do you want to send different kinds of output to different output formats?  [Check This](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/MultipleOutputs.html) If you want to filter out or do manipulations on the values from the map, reduce is the best place to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [`ChainReducer`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/ChainReducer.html) to create a job of the form `[MAP+ / REDUCE MAP*]` i.e. several Maps followed by a reducer and then another series of maps that start with working on the output of the Reducer. The final output is the output of the last Mapper in series.

Alternatively, you can have multiple jobs that start sequentially and the output of the reducer of the previous is the input to the next . But, this causes unnecessary IO incase you are not interested in the intermediate output

Answer (score 0):

Do whatever you want inside the reducer, create a **FSDataOutputStream** and write the output through it.

**For example :**

```
public static class TokenCounterReducer extends
            Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,
                Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(context.getConfiguration());
            FSDataOutputStream out = fs.create(new Path("/path/to/your/file"));
            //do the manipulation and write it down to the file
            out.write(......);
            int sum = 0;
            for (IntWritable value : values) {
                sum += value.get();
            }
            context.write(key, new IntWritable(sum));
        }
    }
```